# JS change socket namespace from client when click on button

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm developping simple app with nodejs and socket.io.
I created two channels and I want my client connect one of channels when click on button. The problem is I don't get response from server

This is my code :

// SERVER side

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var nameSpaceWeek = io.of('/week');
var nameSpaceDay = io.of('/day');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendfile('MDC.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("User = " + socket.id)
});

nameSpaceDay.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('someone connected on namespace day');
    nameSpaceDay.emit('hiDay', 'Hello everyone on namespace day!');
});

nameSpaceWeek.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('someone connected on namespace week');
    nameSpaceDay.emit('hiWeek', 'Hello everyone on namespace week!');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on localhost:3000');
});
```

// CLIENT SIDE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>Hello world</title></head>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
    var socket = io();

    function setDay(){
        console.log("setDay");
        socket = io.connect('/day');
        console.log(socket)
    }

socket.on('hiDay',function(data){
    console.log("hiDay")
    console.log("data = ." + data + ".")
    document.getElementById('message-container').innerHTML = 'Update day'
    console.log("data = ." + data + ".")
});

function setWeek(){
    console.log("setWeek");
    socket = io.connect('/week');        
    console.log(socket)
}

socket.on('hiWeek',function(data){
    console.log("hiWeek")
    document.getElementById('message-container').innerHTML = 'Update Week'
    //document.getElementById('message-container').innerHTML = data
    console.log(data)
});

</script>
<body>
    <div id="message-container"></div>
    <div id="error-container"></div>
    <button type="button" name="button" onclick="setWeek()">Week</button>
    <button type="button" name="button" onclick="setDay()">Day</button>
</body>
```

In my client, I created two button and when I click on one I want change socket namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `setDay()` or `setWeek()`, you are creating a whole new socket.io connection and thus overwriting your previous `socket` variable.  The `socket.on(`hiDay`, ...)` and `socket.on('hiWeek', ...)` handlers you have are ONLY on the first socket you created, not on the newly created sockets, thus you never see the messages on those.

To fix, add those message handlers only to the right socket after you've connected to that namespace.

```
function setWeek() {
    // close previous socket.io connection
    socket.close();

    // make new connection to new namespace
    console.log("setWeek");
    socket = io.connect('/week');        
    console.log(socket)

    // add event handler for new socket
    socket.on('hiWeek',function(data){
        console.log("hiWeek")
        document.getElementById('message-container').innerHTML = 'Update Week'
        console.log(data)
    });
}
```

Then, do the same thing for the `setDay()` function.

And, as shown here you probably want to disconnect the previous connection when changing namespaces too so you don't necessarily leave connections that you aren't using any more.

---

FYI, you also had a typo where this:

```
nameSpaceDay.emit('hiWeek', 'Hello everyone on namespace week!');
```

should have been this:

```
nameSpaceWeek.emit('hiWeek', 'Hello everyone on namespace week!');
```

Final, tested and working code is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>Hello world</title></head>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
    var socket = io();

    function setDay(){
        socket.close();

        console.log("setDay");
        socket = io.connect('/day');

        socket.on('hiDay',function(data){
            console.log("hiDay")
            document.getElementById('message-container').innerHTML = 'Update day';
            console.log(data);
        });     
    }



    function setWeek() {
        // close previous socket.io connection
        socket.close();

        // make new connection to new namespace
        console.log("setWeek");
        socket = io.connect('/week');        

        // add event handler for new socket
        socket.on('hiWeek',function(data){
            console.log("hiWeek");
            document.getElementById('message-container').innerHTML = 'Update Week';
            console.log(data);
        });
    }

</script>
<body>
    <div id="message-container"></div>
    <div id="error-container"></div>
    <button type="button" name="button" onclick="setWeek()">Week</button>
    <button type="button" name="button" onclick="setDay()">Day</button>
</body>
```

And server code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var path = require('path');

var nameSpaceWeek = io.of('/week');
var nameSpaceDay = io.of('/day');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'socket-io-namespace.html'));
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("User = " + socket.id)
});

nameSpaceDay.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('someone connected on namespace day');
    nameSpaceDay.emit('hiDay', 'Hello everyone on namespace day!');
});

nameSpaceWeek.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('someone connected on namespace week');
    nameSpaceWeek.emit('hiWeek', 'Hello everyone on namespace week!');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on localhost:3000');
});
```

Comment: I made changes but it's the same result

Comment: @baudic_j - When I run it with the desired changes, it works just fine for me.  You apparently did not make the changes correctly or I was not clear to you about what you should do.

Comment: @baudic_j - For some reason, the `setDay()` method is working fine, but `setWeek()` is not.  I'm investigating.

Comment: @baudic_j - I found the additional problem.  You had `nameSpaceDay.emit('hiWeek', 'Hello everyone on namespace week!');` when you should have had `nameSpaceWeek.emit('hiWeek', 'Hello everyone on namespace week!');`

Comment: I understand and I made it and it's work for setday but not for setWeek... strange

Comment: @baudic_j - See my recent comments.  You had another typo.

Comment: I have validated your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a connect(ns) function you can reconstruct the socket event listener when the namespace changes. The following should work:

```
        <script>
            var connect = function (ns) {
                return io.connect(ns, {
                    query: 'ns=' + ns,
                    resource: "socket.io"
                }).on('hiWeek', function (data) {
                    console.log("hiWeek")
                    document.getElementById('message-container').innerHTML = 'Update Week'
                    //document.getElementById('message-container').innerHTML = data
                    console.log(data)
                }).on('hiDay', function (data) {
                console.log("hiDay")
                console.log("data = ." + data + ".")
                document.getElementById('message-container').innerHTML = 'Update day'
                console.log("data = ." + data + ".")
            });
            }

            var socket = io();

            function setDay() {
                console.log("setDay");
                socket = connect('/day');
                console.log(socket);
            }

            function setWeek() {
                console.log("setWeek");
                socket = connect('/week');        
                console.log(socket);
            }


        </script>
```

Comment: In your function, the socket will automaticly be connected on 'hiWeek' and 'hiDay' ?

Comment: While it is true there are listeners for both `hiDay` and `hiWeek` it will only respond to events from the namespace specified. Meaning if on the server there is a mismatch like namespaceDay.emit('hiWeek',data)  it will still catch the event

Comment: but if you set the namespace to /week you will not receive the hiDay since it comes from the other namespace on the server.