# How to emit from the default namespace to a custom namespace?

Tags: reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I have a React app using Socket.io. I use the default namespace `/` and a custom namespace `/test`. I need to be able to emit from a namespace to another, but I only managed to get it work from the custom to the default.

On client side, the event listener is on the root (`App.js`):

```
componentDidMount() {
  socket.on('test_listener', (data) => {
    // Some code
  })
}
```

The connection is initialized with redux:

```
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';

const initialState = {
  initializeSocket: socketIOClient('http://localhost:3000/'),
  ...
}
```

On server side, here is the code:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) { 

  socket.on('something', (data) => {

    io.of('/test').emit('test_listener', data); // Not working
    socket.broadcast.emit('test_listener', data); // Is working

  })

});
```

I know for sure that `io.of('namespace').emit('event_name', data);` is supposed to work as it is settled in the [Socket.io's Emit cheatsheet](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/). And the event listener on client side is working since I get something with the `broadcast.emit`.

Plus, I can emit from `/test` to `/` with this code:

```
socket.on('join_namespace_test', data => {

  // [...] Some code to check if the namespace exists

  io.of('/test').on('connection', function (nspSocket) {

    nspSocket.on('do_something', (data) => {
      io.of('/').emit('another_action', data); // This one is working fine
    })

  })

  // [...] Some code to add the user to the namespace /test (switching from default)
}
```

**Any idea why the emit from `/` to `/test` is not working?**
I don't get any error, nothing happens.

---

**Edit:** after further research, I found out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48037918/9718056):

> You can't "switch" namespaces on an existing connection. You connect to a specific namespace when the connection is made and once made, it can't be changed.

To be sure that the problem doesn't come from another part of the project, I reproduced the issue on a fiddle. The emit from default to custom still doesn't work and I also noticed that the `broadcast` has a strange behaviour when the client switch from default to custom and then go back to default (it emits to the sender while it shouldn't).

So, given the fact that the issue might be the way the client switch between the default and the custom namespace and not the emit itself, maybe rooms would be a better option? Or maybe I should find a way to drop the connections before switching, but is it recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of tests, the only solution that worked is to close the previous connection before switching to another namespace, and then to call the socket listener again. When a `socket.on` is initialized, it will only work on the namespace/connection is was set on. [This post helped me to find the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45312018/9718056).

For a simple code out of redux, the solution could look like this (client side, no change needed on server side):

```
var socket = io();
listen();

function switchNamespace(namespace) {
  socket.close(); // Close the current connection
  socket = io(namespace);
  listen();
}

function listen() {
  socket.on('test_listener', (data) => {
    // Some code
  })
}
```

As a side note, initializing `io.of('/namespace').on('connection', ...` inside or outside of the default `io.on('connection', ...` didn't make any difference.

In our case, this solution was not fitting the current project structure, so we decided to use rooms instead.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show me how the connection is initialized client side ?

It should be like that :

```
const socket = io('/test')
```

If you broadcast something on the `default` namespace, and the client receive it, it means the client is connected to the `/` namespace and not the `/test` one.

On client side, I'm pretty sure you can not listen to multiple namespace on the same socket. If you want to do it, you need to initialize multiple sockets on the client :

```
const socketDefault = io()
const socketTest = io('/test')
```

---

**EDIT**

Your other response is good, if you need to use only one namespace at the same time.

However, if you want a true multi-namespace handling, a code a little bit better could be the following :

```
class Sockets {

  // Used as Handler for the proxy for `multi` method, should work, but didn't test it
  get (target, prop) {
    return (...args) => {
      const output = [];
      for(const alias of target._aliases) {
        output.push(target._sockets[alias][prop](...args))
      }
      return output;
    }
  }

  // Used to proxy methods, and only methods
  multi(aliases) {
    return new Proxy({ _sockets: this, _aliases: aliases }, this); // Use the above `get` for all undefined methods
  }

  addNamespace(alias, namespace) {
    if (this[alias]) {
      return false
    }

    Object.defineProperty(this, alias, {
      enumerable: true,
      writable: false,
      configurable: false,
      value: io(namespace)
    })
  }
}

const sockets = new Sockets()
sockets.addNamespace('default')
sockets.addNamespace('test', '/test')
sockets.addNamespace('toto', '/toto')

sockets.test.on('test_listener', (data) => {
  // Some code
})

sockets.toto.on('test_listener', (data) => {
  // Some code
})

sockets.multi(['test', 'toto', 'default']).on('common_listener', (data) => {

})
```

Comment: I edited the question with more details, I think the problem comes from the way the user switch between namespaces. On client side, redux is dealing with the socket connection, when the user go to another namespace, the state is changed with the reducer. I added a fiddle with a similar logic (but without redux) to test out the issue.

Comment: I didn't get notifications for this thread, sorry for the delay, I don't understand why you don't open multiple sockets, if you switch pretty often, I don't think closing and reopening is worth it...